# How to make a Crystal Report in a C# Windows Forms Application which populates data by calling Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am willing to use `Crystal Reports` in my `C# Windows Forms` Project in `VS 2012`. So far I have done and tested data insertions and retrievals successfully by using `Entity Framework` and `SQL Server` `Stored Procedures`. So, as an example, I have successful code to retrieve data using a `stored procedure` and display the result in a `data grid view` as follows:

```
    using ( TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities() )
    {
        //For setting the data source for the dataGridView
        dgViewResults.DataSource = db.uspGetReadersByCategory(SelectedCategory);        
    }
```

Above code works fine without having to code anything else, by using my entities.

All I need to know is, Is there such a way to use this method calls to retrieve and set data to `Crystal Reports`? Is there any, can you please suggest me some web links to follow because I tried to search of my own and ended up with a confused mind.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824591/howto-bind-crystal-reports-to-entity-framework

Comment: You might also want to consider looking into Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS). Crystal Reports makes me shudder.

Comment: @Carl, No. I am specifically looking for a solution where I can easily set the report source as a result coming from a stored procedure call. The solution they suggest in the other question is having an intermediate `XSD` Data Set.

Comment: @LeeO., May be. But it is required to build the report using **Crystal Reports**, **Entity Framework** and **SQL Server Stored Procedures**.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it this way:

```
Report.CrystalReport1 report = new Report.CrystalReport1();

using (ReadersDataModel db = new ReadersDataModel())
{
    var readers = db.uspGetReadersByCategory("SelectedCategory");
    report.SetDataSource(readers);
}

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

From this solution:
[HowTo Bind Crystal Reports to Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824591/howto-bind-crystal-reports-to-entity-framework)

More info on Entity Framework calling Stored Procedure:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx