# How to fill data table from SQL result into columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ms-access

i need to put this data into data table in one row

| EmpID | Day | Date | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday | 03/07/2023 | Location 1 |
| 1 | Monday | 03/07/2023 | Location 2 |
| 1 | Monday | 03/07/2023 | Location 3 |
| 1 | Monday | 03/07/2023 | Location 4 |
| 1 | Sunday | 02/07/2023 | Location 4 |
| 1 | Sunday | 02/07/2023 | Location 3 |
| 1 | Sunday | 02/07/2023 | Location 4 |

like this,

| EmpID | Day | Date | Location | Location | Location | Location | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday | 03/07/2023 | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 | Location 4 |  |
| 1 | Sunday | 02/07/2023 | Location 4 | Location 3 | Location 4 | - |  |

can anyone help me

i try this code by use Arr

the max columns of location will be 15

I try this so do the rows

```
for (DateTime d = dateSTART.Value; d <= dateEND.Value; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT myLocation FROM EmpTable where EmpID=1 and myDate=d", con);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        theLocation.Add(dr["myLocation"].ToString());
    }
    string[] casesArray = theLocation.ToArray();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(casesArray);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm asking because what you're asking for is fundamentally incompatible with how all "table"-based data systems work: they're based on Relational Calculus which is row ("relation") orientated, and not columnar and columns are _static_, but what you're asking for requires _variadic_ columns, which isn't something "tables" (in any language) support, by-design.

Comment: i need it for crystal report because i have some problems in "Format with multiple columns" and suppress if duplicated

Comment: use group by with day and date after create your readModel table

Comment: i convert the data row in location to Array but i have problem with sort the group by date

Comment: Post your code. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: The question you asked is not clear, please give us more detail from your problem

Comment: i havent more information from your problem please edit your question for more detail. but you before the group by can sort your items with date after group by there too, maybe work for your scenario

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824591/howto-bind-crystal-reports-to-entity-framework) may be relevant if you are able to use entity framework

Comment: if this was just an access problem, I would tell you to use the query designer to run a crosstab query on the data.  Then save the crosstab to a new table with a make table query.  then use whatever technology to view the new table with the correct shape.

Comment: Is that 2-row table you show (the second table) the one-row solution yo are looking for. I'm confused

Comment: What you are looking for is a non-table solution. You don't know in advance how many `location` columns you are going to need. You can represent the data structure you describe in memory (fairly easily). In addition,  _No SQL_ databases can be used to store what you are describing. However, if you try to use an ADO.NET DataTable for this, you will drive yourself nuts.

Comment: the max number is about 15 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- In SQL, you can simply concatenate locations into a single string:

```sql
    SELECT [EmpID] , [Day] , [Date] , STRING_AGG([Location] , ',') AS Locations 
    FROM EmpTable 
    GROUP BY [EMPID] , [Day] , [Date]
```

It's readable enough to use in report. However, if exact columnar output is required as shown in attached image, then a new table (similar as EmpTable but with 15 fields for locations) should be used and the above query results needs to be processed.

2- The ms-access tag for this question is confusing.
Anyway, a transformed crosstab query in access can be used to produce a columnar ouput **similar** (but not exactly) to the desired output:

```sql
    TRANSFORM Location
    SELECT EmpID , FIRST([Day]) AS WeekDay , [Date]
    FROM EmpTable
    GROUP BY [EmpID] , [Date]
    PIVOT [Location]
```